# Rust, Windows 10: Diesel doesn't work, diesel setup provides no output

Tags: windows, postgresql, rust, orm, rust-diesel

I am new to Rust, and I wanted to try Diesel with Postgres. I have followed the steps described here:

https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started

But unfortunately, when it comes do `diesel setup`, nothing happens. I receive no output, no error messages, nothing. I have installed diesel_cli with the command `install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres` , I have Postgres 13 on Windows 10.

This is what I have in my .env file : `DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:pwd@localhost:5432/diesel` (with pwd being my password). I have created a database named "diesel", and it is running on the Postgres server, with default settings. It is currently empty, with no tables.

I receive no output from `diesel setup` or `diesel migrate generate create_posts`. Not even an error message.

Did someone else encounter this problem as well? Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: You are right, I have edited the text!

Comment: have you solve the problem? I encounter the exact same problem

Answer (score 5):

If you use powershell in windows, it will not give error message.
echo $LASTEXITCODE on powershell will give the error code.

[get lastexitcode](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2015#issuecomment-474172079)

Using command line will give the error message.

I added this "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" to my path environment variable.

Now diesel setup and other cli commands are working.

[Reference](https://dev.to/ssivakumar77/rust-diesel-fixing-issues-with-setup-3k56)

Comment: Using powershell embedded terminal in VSCode, I not only had to restart powershell, but also VSCode as a whole after adding my postgres bin to path.

Comment: That's normal. When modifying env var you have to restart the process that would use this path. It's kind of annoying, but it is expected